# Play sound in Godot when a kinematicbody2D collides with a tile map?

Tags: godot

The player in my game is a kinematicbody2D, and I want a sound effect to play whenever it collides with the tile map. My player uses `move_and_slide()` to collide with the tile map.

How can I trigger a sound to play when the player hits the tilemap? I only want the sound to play after the player initially collides with the tile map; it shouldn’t play over and over if the player is sitting on the floor.

I know how to use sounds with the StreamAudioPlayer, I just need help triggering the sound to play when I want it to play.

Comment: Do you just want to play a sound when your player lands on the ground? Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Lands on the ground, hits the wall, or hits the ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler way to keep track of `is_on_floor` before and after `move_and_slide`.

For example:

```
var was_on_floor = is_on_floor()
move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)
if is_on_floor() and not was_on_floor:
    $sound.play()
```

Whenever you call `move_and_slide` Godot updates the values you get from `is_on_floor`, `is_on_wall` and `is_on_ceiling`. To know what is wall, floor or ceiling, Godot uses the vector you pass as second parameter (if you pass `Vector2.ZERO` then everything is wall).

---

If you only care to check if it collided with something at all, you may use `get_slide_count` after `move_and_slide`. The function `get_slide_count` should give you `0` if there were no collisions:

```
if get_slide_count() > 0:
    $sound.play()
```

---

Or you could check if the velocity that `move_and_slide` returns a different velocity that the one you passed. Meaning it did collide (or slide).

```
var old_velocity = velocity
velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)
if velocity != old_velocity:
    $sound.play()
```

---

Alternatively you may use `get_slide_collision`, which gives you a [`KinematicCollision2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematiccollision2d.html) object:

```
for i in get_slide_count():
    var collision = get_slide_collision(i)
    print("Collided with: ", collision.collider.name)
```

Which will let you identify with what did the `KinematicBody2D` collide with, and then you could pick a sound accordingly.